# rational points and a local perturbation of an elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, rational-points

Let $E_{a,b}$ be an elliptic curve defined by the equation $y^{2}=x^3+ax+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Suppose that for $a=a_{0}$ and $b=b_{0}$ the rank of $E_{a_{0},b_{0}}(\mathbb{Q})=1$.

**question:** 
is there an $\epsilon> 0$ such that for any $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbb{Q}^{2}$ and $|\alpha-a_{0}|+|\beta -b_{0}|< \epsilon$ then  the rank of $E_{\alpha,\beta}(\mathbb{Q})=1$.

Comment: Arithmetic properties like the rank of the Mordell-Weil group are not continuous with respect to the real (or the $p$-adic) topology. A more interesting question would be: Given $\epsilon>0$ is there a curve of rank $1$?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich is it a heuristic observation or a precise mathematical statement ? I'm talking about continuity.

Comment: Heuristically, I believe that the answer is "no" for all $a_0$ and $b_0$. A counter-example can be constructed as follows. Take an elliptic surface over $\mathbb{Q}$ with rank $2$. By Silverman's specialisation theorem, the rank of each fibre is at least $2$ (but often larger) except for a finite number of fibres. At an exceptional fibre of rank $1$, you will get a counter-example. For instance $a_0=2$, $b_0=1$ is of rank $1$, but the family $E_t:y^2=x^3+(-t^2+t+2)\,x+1$ is of rank $2$ as it contains $(0,1)$ and $(t,t+1)$. For all $t$ close to zero the rank of $E_t$ will be $2$ or larger.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I'm satisfied with your comment. I think it would be better if you transform it to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Can you do the converse : from an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with a point $P$ of infinite order construct an elliptic curve $E_t/\mathbb{Q}(t)$ with a point $P(t)\in E_t,P  = P(0)$ ?

Comment: @reuns: sure, for any field $k$ and points $P$ and $Q$ defined over $k$ you can find $A$ and $B$ in $k$ such that the Weierstrass equation passes through $P$ and $Q$ except in special cases like $x_P=x_Q$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I meant with $A(t),B(t)\in \mathbb{Q}(t)$ non-constant and $P(t) \in \mathbb{Q}(t)$ (so we can use it to understand perturbations of $E$)

Comment: @reuns: me, too. $k$ can be $\mathbb{Q}(t)$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I believe that reuns has something different in mind, namely that for instance $E_t$ shouldn't be isotrivial (its $j$-invariant should be non-constant in $t$). So the point of infinite order on $E$ should arise from specializing a point on $E_t$ (where $E=E_0$) over $\mathbb Q(t)$ which has infinite order by geometric reasons.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If I pick $P$ with non-constant coordinates in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, say as linear polynomials as I did in my example, I get a linear relation on $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$. Among all these there are non-isotrivial surfaces. For any $t$ except a finite number the point $P_t$ will be of infinite order if $P_0$ is. That is easy. What is not so clear is to take $P$ and $Q$ with $P_0=Q_0$ of infinite order and make sure that they are linearly indep on the surface. Checking that there is some $t$ for which they are is enough as I did in the example.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Sorry, of course you are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A counter-example, showing that the answer is "no" for some $(a_0,b_0)$ can be constructed as follows. Take an elliptic surface over $\mathbb{Q}$ with rank $2$. By Silverman's specialisation theorem, the rank of each fibre is at least $2$ (but often larger) except for a finite number of fibres. At an exceptional fibre of rank $1$, you will get a counter-example.

For instance $a_0=2$, $b_0=1$ the curve is of rank $1$, but the family $E_t:y^2=x^3+(−t^2+t+2)x+1$ is of rank at least $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ as it contains $(0,1)$ and $(t,t+1)$. For all $t$ close to zero the rank of $E_t(\mathbb{Q})$ will be $2$ or larger.

I believe a similar argument should work in general and show that the answer is always "no".

Arithmetic properties like the rank of the Mordell-Weil group are not continuous in the real or $p$-adic topology. For instance, the number of prime factors of numerator and denominator of $\Delta$ will have an influence on the rank.

In the above example as $t=1/n$ approaches $0$, the rank will jump around $2$ and $3$ and sometimes larger values rather randomly:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
t=\tfrac{1}{n} & \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{3} & \tfrac{1}{4} &\tfrac{1}{5}
& \tfrac{1}{6} & \tfrac{1}{7} & \tfrac{1}{8} & \tfrac{1}{9} & \tfrac{1}{10} &
\tfrac{1}{11} & \tfrac{1}{12} & \tfrac{1}{13} & \tfrac{1}{14} &\tfrac{1}{15} & \tfrac{1}{16} & \tfrac{1}{16} & \tfrac{1}{17} & \tfrac{1}{18} & \tfrac{1}{19}\\
\text{rank} & 1 & 3  & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 &2 \\
\end{array}
$$